# Change value column a if column b contains conditional string

Tags: r, replace, match, grepl

This issue is giving me a lot of trouble, even though it should be fixed eaily. I have a dataset with the columns id and poster. I want to change the poster's value if the id value contains a certain string. See data below:

test_df

```
id                   poster
143537222999_2054    Kevin
143115551234_2049    Dave
14334_5334           Eric
1456322_4334         Mandy
143115551234_445633  Patrick
143115551234_4321    Lars
143537222999_56743   Iris
```

I would like to get

test_df

```
id                   poster
143537222999_2054    User
143115551234_2049    User
14334_5334           Eric
1456322_4334         Mandy
143115551234_445633  User
143115551234_4321    User
143537222999_56743   User
```

Both the columns are characters. I would like to change the poster's value to "User" if id value contains "143537222999", OR "143115551234". I have tried the following codes:

**Match within/which**

```
test_df <- within(test_df, poster[match('143115551234', test_df$id) | match('143537222999', test_df$id)] <- 'User')
```

This code gave me no errors, but it didn't change any of the values in the poster column. When I replace within for which, I get the error:

```
test_df <- which(test_df, poster[match('143115551234', test_df$id) | match('143537222999', test_df$id)] <- 'User')
Error in which(test_df, poster[match("143115551234", test_df$id) |  : 
  argument to 'which' is not logical
```

**Match different variant**

```
test_df <- test_df[match(id, test_df, "143115551234") | match(id, test_df, "143537222999"), test_df$poster] <- 'User'
```

This code gives me the error:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, match(id, test_df, "143115551234") |  : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In match(id, test_df, "143115551234") :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
2: In match(id, test_df, "143537222999") :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

After looking up this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589354/struggling-with-integers-maximum-integer-size) I found out that the integers in R are 32-bits and the maximum value of an integer is 2147483647. I'm not sure why i'm getting this error because R states that my column is a character.

```
> lapply(test_df, class)

$poster
[1] "character"

$id
[1] "character"
```

**Grepl**

```
test_df[grepl("143115551234", id | "143537222999", id), poster := "User"]
```

This code raises the error:

```
Error in `:=`(poster, "User") : could not find function ":="
```

I'm not sure what the best way is to fix this error, I have tried multiple variaties and keep getting across different errors.

I have tried multiple answers from multiple [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48261387/how-to-conditionally-replace-values-in-r-data-frame-using-if-then-statement) [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23396279/when-trying-to-replace-values-missing-values-are-not-allowed-in-subscripted-as) [were](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38575193/r-conditionally-replace-values-in-a-subset-of-columns) [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214303/conditional-replacement-of-values-in-a-data-frame) before on here, but I still can't get to fix some errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grepl` with `ifelse`:

```
df$poster <- ifelse(grepl("143537222999|143115551234", df$id), "User", df$poster)
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You may try this using `grepl`.

```
df[grepl('143115551234|143537222999', df$id),"poster"] <- "User"
```

So, all the true for above matched in poster column getting replaced by "User"

```
> df[grepl('143115551234|143537222999', df$id),"poster"] <- "User"
> df
                   id poster
1   143537222999_2054   User
2   143115551234_2049   User
3          14334_5334   Eric
4        1456322_4334  Mandy
5 143115551234_445633   User
6   143115551234_4321   User
7  143537222999_56743   User
```

Comment: This answer works as well Thanks! It looks like I had the syntax wrong.